# Android - Pass complex objects between activities with Parcelable or Json?

Tags: android, json, android-activity, parcelable, gson

I was wondering what is the best performative and simpler way to travel objects between activities between these two methods. I know Parcelable is specifically designed for Android, but what about using Gson to parse a complex object or an array of it and setting it in a intent extra as a string, retrieve it in the second activity and parse it back  as object. In my example I have a list of Content and every Content has a list of Subject inside. Is traveling json a better or worse way than traveling objects using parcelable? 
I'm excluding options like saving on disk or using serializable.

Comment: IMHO, either these should be combined into a single activity, or you should be implementing some process-wide cache that both activities can access.

Comment: Neither. Both Parcelables and JSON involve a lot of overhead — not a lot in absolute units, but *a lot*, compared to simply assigning to variable. Use them only when you really want to serialize something or have to employ them for other reasons (such as when you have to abide to Intent/Bundle/AIDL contract or to receive data from REST API). Unlike Parcelable JSON stores names of parameters, so it is more human-readable, but takes bigger toll on memory because of it.

Comment: As for relative performance (as in "the CPU time, wasted on (de)serialization"), there should be no difference between two whatsoever. Many undeservedly popular JSON-handling libraries (khm-G-kham-SON) use Reflection, so their speed sucks. But a well written JSON deserializer, such as LoganSquare, is identical to Parcelable in terms of serialization speed.

Comment: Extremely helpful answer user1643723, that's exactly the type of answer that I wanted, and it enlighted me. And didn't know about LoganSquare and I'll give it a try. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1.** Store data in a centralized object (singleton etc) & then access that object in Activity.

Let say you have a singleton class AppData. Store data in AppData. Access data using AppData in your activities directly.

**Option 2.** Implement [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) in corresponding classes, then pass parcelable objects to activity via intent OR store parcelable data in preference.
[How to make entity parcelable with just copy paste](http://parcelabler.com/)

**Option 3.** Implement Serializable in corresponding classes